# Using did as boolean flag name

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

I named one of my boolean parameters `didInfoChange`.

Many people on my team tell me to change it to `isInfoChanged`, which I don't agree. It maybe because my team members aren't native English speaker (neither am I), but I feel that `ifInfoChanged` is just isn't right.

`didInfoChange -> Did information change? -> True/False`

is pretty understand in my oppinion

`isInfoChanged -> is info changed?`

just does not sound right.
It's probably not a big deal to fight about this, but I did some search and people do not really use `did` for flag name. I'm ok with `hasInfoChanged` but `has` and `did` is basically the same thing.

I'm wondering why is `did` not ok?

Comment: I would favor `infoChanged`. But if everyone on my team wanted me to use the wrong name, I might comply, for the sake of harmony.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would have been ok with `infoChanged` too, but since everything else is done with `is` so everyone want to stick `is` in front of everything. It is taking a lot of time since my PR isn't reviewed because people are arguing about this. However, I feel if something isn't right then it should be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions here:

**1) Which is better, `didInfoChange` or `isInfoChanged`?**

The English word "change" can be transitive or intransitive, but in this context it is clear that *"the info is changed"* and *"the info did change"* mean exactly the same thing. (There is a subtle difference in connotation, but it is of no importance here.) The two names have the same length. There seems to be no difference except style convention.

**2) If your way is better than theirs, what should you do?**

Consider the consequences of your actions.

If you have the power to persuade the rest of the team to use your variable name, at no cost, then do so. If doing so would cause stress (e.g. by commanding your subordinates to do something they consider a bad idea), then the improvement in style probably isn't the cost to the group dynamic.

If you cannot persuade them, but you can prolong the argument and prevent the team from doing constructive work, then... don't. Use their variable name.

If you cannot prolong the argument, but you can make yourself unpopular by being argumentative, then... don't. Use their variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Beside *is* it is also sometimes admissible to use *has* in naming Boolean getter-methods, depending on which auxiliary verb would be used in spoken language; I never saw *did* as part of a Boolean identifier.

With **hasInfoChanged** you would keep the participle ending *(e)d*. Maybe that satisfies the rest of your team.

*infoChanged* could be mistaken for an EventHandler-Delegate.

Unfortunately I am not a native English speaker, either.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context and what this field "really" expresses in semantics.

- `didInfoChange` puts emphasis on the completed action (past-tense implied) by "did" + action-verb
- `isInfoChanged` puts emphasis and indicates the current-state when asking now by `is` + state; where the past-tense is indicated by the passive "changed"

Note: `Info` is the vague part in the name. `is` is a common indicator for boolean fields or getters - indicating a question (same like `has` or `can`). `did` is rather rarely used because we usually ask for the current state at runtime using `is`. The *completion* or *history* can be expressed by other parts of the name, like specific action-verb in past-tense.

#### Other ways of recording/asking for change

What about asking more about the context of this change:

1. **Who** did change the information ? Like an audit field (`changedBy`) conveying also who did change something.
2. **When** was the information changed ? Like a audit date/time field (`changedAt`), not only telling that it was changed, but also when.
3. **What** information was changed ? Like capturing the change itself (`lastChange`) which could also be null if not changed at all.

In most ORM-frameworks which capture audit-information like this (when/who/what was changed) we can see fields like `createdBy` or `createdAt` for the initial user and timestamp when created, `modifiedBy` or `modifiedAt` for the user and timestamp that last updated or changed the object.

Sometimes also a version-indicator helps to keep track of the number of changes.

#### Keep it simple

One compromise could be inspired by KISS-principle:
Have a boolean field `changed` which could for enrichment-purpose also hold a timestamp along with a getter named `isChanged` to query the current state like asking a human question like:

> is [this] changed ?

Note: `[this]` is implied when invoking the method on the object like `this.isChanged()`.